# why 2nd click action is not run when browser is Google Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I don't konw why 2nd click action is not be run when browser is Google Chrome.
The 1st input action: input text has been done, then 2nd click action failed to be run
And there's nothing happened on the UI.
Could anybody can tell me the reason?

test link:https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss

> from selenium import webdriver driver=webdriver.Chrome()
>   driver.get('https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss')  driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys("7383AC1") 
>   driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

Answer (score 0):

That page has 3 elements with the name "submit", so ChromeDriver is probably trying to click one that you're not expecting.

Try finding by xpath or css. I'm more familiar with XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='modelnumber']/../following-sibling::td/input[@name='submit']").click()
```

Comment: what happens? A little more info is required

Comment: the object can be found, but the click action still not be run. And it's strange, there's no any err msg. the situation is same to my scripts

Comment: It's possibly because the input is of type "image", and not type "submit". Try using the JavascriptExecutor class to locator and click it, which may fire the onclick event differently to how ChromeDriver does